# Disable all https in WordPress

Tags: admin, ssl, https

Recently I moved my WordPress to another server (MediaTemple), but now my admin is redirecting for HTTPS all the time, but I don't have SSL enabled on my domain, so it just keep warning that is not the same server and bla bla bla... Well, I want to disable all those https request on WordPress. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe WordPress sends `HTTPS` requests unless it has been told to do so. It sounds like you need to undo some previous configuration -- most likely change/remove the `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` constant.

You may have plugins participating as well though. Make sure to check that.

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL